# how to get the absolute position of a section header in tableview？

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

how to get the absolute position of a section header in tableview？

I have already used the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` to get the header's view.But now i need to get the absolute position of this view in the screen.
the return value's frame is not the absolute position in the screen.I also tried to call superview,but it seems not work.

Comment: What's the return value?  Sounds like you'll have to take into account the offset of the tableview and the tableview's content offset (I'm not entirely sure if there is a content offset).

Comment: I just need to get the section header's absolute position in the screen.But I dont't know how...(Using   tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: seems not the correct way)

Comment: Finally I solved my problem by setting a tag to my section header's view,and get it with the tag.Many thanks~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method for creating a header view for display. This means, however, that the view *has not* been added to the view hierarchy, rendering it's frame meaningless for your purposes.

Try

```
UIView *headerView = [tableView headerViewForSection:sectionIndex];
```

instead. From there you can try the following methods on the returned view to get the rect of the view in any other view's coordinate system:

```
[headerView convertRect:[headerView bounds] toView:[headerView window]];
```

Comment: Finally I solved my problem by setting a tag to my section header's view,and get it with the tag.Many thanks~

Comment: [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:section]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your top-level view directly contains table view which in turn contains header:

```
- (CGRect) getHeaderAbsoluteFrame : (UIView *)headerview :(UIView *)tableview
{
  CGRect frame = headerview.frame;
  CGRect tableFrame = tableview.frame;

  float x = tableview.  origin.x + headerview.frame.origin.x;
  float y = tableview.frame.origin.y + headerview.frame.origin.y;

  CGRect rect = CGRectMake (x,y,headerview.frame.size.width, headerview.frame.size.height);
  return rect;
}
```