# Get absolute/global position of table header section while accounting for horizontal scroll

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, qheaderview

I'm creating a column tracking layout that inherits from QHBoxLayout, which will align a couple of line edits to the table columns:

[image]

To do that, I calculate the absolute screen position of each section size in `ColumnAlignedLayout::setGeometry()` using this code:

```
void ColumnAlignedLayout::setGeometry(const QRect &r)
{
    QHBoxLayout::setGeometry(r);
    int widgetX = parentWidget()->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)).x();
    int headerX = headerView->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)).x();
    int delta = headerX - widgetX;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < headerView->count(); ++ii) {
        int pos = headerView->sectionPosition(ii);
        int size = headerView->sectionSize(ii);

        auto item = itemAt(ii);
        auto r = item->geometry();
        r.setLeft(pos + delta);
        r.setWidth(size);
        item->setGeometry(r);
    }
}
```

The layout already works, except when the table has a horizontal scroll.

[image]

The full project is at https://github.com/sashoalm/ColumnAlignedLayout, and running it will reproduce the problem easily - just enlarge the columns until the horizontal scrollbar appears, and then scroll until the first column is hidden.

`headerView->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)).x();` gives the same value whether the table has been resized or not.

I found a similar question but it's for objective C, and it doesn't account for scrolling which is my problem.

[how to get the absolute position of a section header in tableview？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905294/how-to-get-the-absolute-position-of-a-section-header-in-tableview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I went into Qt's source for their paint event, assuming they would need the actual position for it, and they use `sectionViewportPosition()`, which gives the actual section position relative to the QTableWidget/QTableView's upper-left corner.

You can use that along with `mapToGlobal()` to get the global horizontal position of the section.